# Display custom message if url fails to load in phonegap inappbrowser

Tags: url, cordova, load, external, inappbrowser

I have created an android app that basically loads the responsive website via phonegap inappbrowser.

Now i want to fancy it up and make it more like an app. So my main problems are

1. When i try to load the app and somehow internet goes off, it displays the url of the website and says website not available. So i want to remove that and display my own custom message. Is that possible? What do i need to do for that?
2. Whenever user clicks on any menu item of the website from the app it gives a blank screen during the page transition/load. Now is there anyway i can show a loading sign every time they click on a menu item?

This is what i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: Please Check your Internet Connection. '); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
    }

    </script>
```

I am using dreamweaver to deal with the html section and phonegap build to compile my app.

I am fairly new at this so please elaborate.

---

```
function onDeviceReady()
        {
            checkConnection();
                } 
    function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
        if(states[networkState]==states[Connection.NONE])
            {alert('No Internet Connection! Please Turn on Wifi or Mobile Data to use this application');}
else
{
var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: Please Check your Internet Connection. '); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}
        }
```

So what if the internet gets turned off in the middle of using the app? Would it work then too? If not then is there any way to get that done too?

Also can you please tell me where to apply the following codes that you had put on your response

```
navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Its loading your homepage....."); 
Below code will stop the loading popup :

navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

Thank you very much. I really am in need for these 2 solutions :(

Answer (score 1):

Hi Finally for me works

onerror function is called when the browser hasn't internet.

onload function is called when exist a internet connection.

```html
<body>
<script>document.write('<img src="http://static.forosdelweb.com/fdwtheme/logo-navidad.png?'+Math.random()+'" style="display:none" onload="alert(&quot;hay internet&quot;)" onerror="alert(&quot;no hay internet&quot;)" />');</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Check internet connection onDeviceReady function with following code.

```
    function onDeviceReady()
        {
            checkConnection();
                } 
    function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
        if(states[networkState]==states[Connection.NONE])
            {alert('No Internet Connection! Please Turn on Wifi or Mobile Data to use this application');}
else
{
//load your pages
}
        }
```

Now if you are loading responsive site then you need to specify loader in that responsive website. But in cordova you can use following code for loader

```
navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Its loading your homepage.....");
```

Below code will stop the loading popup :

```
navigator.notification.activityStop();
```